# Confusion over header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sdl, header-files

I'm a fairly new programmer and i'm making a small game project in Visual Studio / C++ / SDL. So I have my code laid out like this:

prototypes.h:

```
#ifndef PROTOTYPES_H
#define PROTOTYPES_H

#include "constants.h"
#include "globals.h"
#include "functions.h"

struct circle
{
    float x;
    float y;
    int r;
};
//other class declarations
#endif PROTOTYPES_H
```

functions.h:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

#include "SDL_header.h"
#include "prototypes.h"

bool check_collision(circle circle, SDL_Rect rect);
//other function declarations

#endif FUNCTIONS_H
```

Which as far I can tell is completely correct, at least according to [this](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/headerfileincludepatterns.htm#.Utrl5RDFKUk) explanation.
Even when I mouseover the 'circle' in the functions.h file in the IDE I get the correct tooltip 'struct circle' pop up. However when i compile I get the error 'undeclared identifier 'circle'' in reference to functions.h...

what the hell..?

Comment: Use the luxury of `#pragma once`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have a circular inclusion. Prototype.h includes functions.h and functions.h includes prototype.h

Now if a cpp file you are compiling calls prototype.h first the second line will include the content of functions.h which will place a reference to circle struct before its actual definition.

In your case if functions.h includes functions on structures defined in prototype.h there should not be any reason to **include** functions.h from prototype.h.
If you manage the dependencies between header files your code will be much easier to manage..

In your case:

- *function.h depends on prototype.h and must include it*
- *prototype.h must not include function.h*

Also, it is usually worthwhile to keep the class/struct and all its functions in a single header file. Unless the file becomes too big in which case you can split functions it into multiple headers.

NOTE: A brute force solution can be to add a [forward declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) to struct circle just before its usage in functions.h however I would reserve such solutions only for cases where they really can't be avoided

Comment: Right, thanks. That's fairly obvious now I think about it. So what's a better way of structuring my program if I need my classes to be able to access my functions and my functions to be able to access my classes?

Comment: Why do you need prototype.h to be aware of function.h?
Nothing in prototype.h depends on functions.h so you don't need that include. prototype.h includes 3 files but is not using anything from any of them.

Comment: There are other classes in prototype.h which depend on functions, I shortened the file for the purpose of posting it. Actually though I think I could include it in each of the class.cpp's instead to get it to work, originally I just included functions.h in prototypes.h so that all my classes would have access to functions if they needed to.